# Splitting String at a number equal to or greater than it in a javascript

Tags: javascript, string, split

There is a string of positive integers in increasing order. The problem is to split it from the positive integer greater or equal to it.
Example:

```
array = [2,3,5,7,10,19,24,28,30]
```

If given positive integer is 7, the resulting array will be

```
newArray = [7,10,19,24,28,30]
```

If given positive integer is 8, the resulting array will be

```
newArray = [10,19,24,28,30]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please don't expect spoon fed answers. Include an example of your code, what is the problem with it and we can help you better.

Comment: I know how to do it using if else or by loops...but want to know some simpler solution if it is there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the array is ordered, find the value index and slice from it.

```
array.slice(array.findIndex(i => i >= 7))
```

Comment: Totally fails if you use `6` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a reusable function say, `filterArray(array, num)` and implement `Array.filter()` method inside that:

```js
function filterArray(array, num){
  return array.filter(item => item >= num);
}

var array = [2,3,5,7,10,19,24,28,30]
var num = 7;

console.log(filterArray(array, num));

array = [2,3,5,7,10,19,24,28,30]
num = 8;

console.log(filterArray(array, num));
```

Comment: What's the point of creating a wrapper if the standard version is exactly as reusable and still one line?

Comment: @bugs to give abstraction to the function. OP can add more lines of code there. Depends on the scenario

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method for arrays. In this example, if you wanted to only have integers greater than 8, you could do

```
newArray = array.filter(i => i > 8)
```